# What does request.GET.get('page') mean?

Tags: python, django

What does request.GET.get('page') mean?
Also can someone explain what is happening here:

```
def post_list(request):
object_list = Post.published.all()
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)# 3 posts in each page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request,
              'blog/post/list.html',
              {'page': page,
               'posts': posts})
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get

Comment: There may be someone on here that recognizes which library you're using, but you should really include the library you're using here

Answer (score 0):

Simple! it GETs data from a website, the data can be HTML or just plaintext, from the code above it looks like it shows data from a website and renders it in a nice format, probably in a nice webpage GUI? Personally I would do this differently but this doesn't look like the whole code.